# Comparing frequencies in two groups between two time periods

Tags: chi-squared-test, descriptive-statistics, contingency-tables, frequency

I've got data that are essentially set up in two 2x2 frequency tables. I have frequencies that males and females disperse or recruit to a given region. I am interested if the proportion of sexes that disperse has changed between two time periods. An example of this data set is below.

```
          1995-2000
      Dispersed Recruited  Total
 Male    30       300      330
 Female  80       290      370
 Total   110      590      700


         2001-2010
      Dispersed Recruited  Total
 Male    40       250      290
 Female  200      350      550
 Total   240      600      840
```

I would appreciate any help with how approach this question.

Thanks in advance!